# Flutter column with expanding widget inside a scroll view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a column that has content at the top, some more content at the bottom like a footer, and filler space in between.  Additionally it needs to scroll when the screen is too small for the top content + footer content (small devices, keyboard opened etc.)

Something like this

[image: scrolling]

when the content is larger than screen, it should scroll

[image: flex no scroll]

when the content is smaller than screen, flex in middle

Have tried a few different approaches found on SO but cannot figure out how to get this to work.  With a `singleChildScrollView` giving a `Column` infinite height, the `Flexible` will throw an error as it's unbounded.

Code at the moment

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 150,
                        width: 250,
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text('Content')),
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 150,
                        width: 250,
                        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text('Content')),
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 150,
                        width: 250,
                        color: Colors.pink.shade100,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: TextField()),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Text('Flex')),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 100,
                        width: 250,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text('Footer')),
                  ])),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much trial and error, and no success using things like `LayoutBuilder` and `IntrinsicHeight` I finally worked out the solution for the use case I have using `CustomScrollView` and a `Sliver` widget called `SilverFillRemaining`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 150,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text('Content')),
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 150,
                        width: 250,
                        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text('Content')),
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 150,
                        width: 250,
                        color: Colors.pink.shade100,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: TextField()),
                    Flexible(
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Text('Flex')),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 100,
                        width: 250,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text('Footer')),
                  ]),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helps anyone else with a similar use case

Comment: Worked for me a treat, now my website has a footer, regardless of the size of the browser, thanks

Comment: Excellent, Simple and robust solution, thanks